# How can I perform an onclick call to a function provided in a firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon

I am inserting a link into a webpage, and when that link is clicked I want it to call a function in my addon js file.

i.e.

```
<a id="1-link" onclick="hideDiv(1)">hide</a>
```

Which has been inserted into the HTML and would ideally call `hideDiv()` in the .js file of my firefox addon, however console is complaining that `ReferenceError: hideDiv is not defined` presumably because it doesn't know where to look. So how can specify that I want it to be called from my addon .js file?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Anatomy of a WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) page (perhaps work through reading the pages linked from there). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will also want to read [Content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts). Generally, the solution is to use `addEventListener()`, which is what you *should be doing* as a default solution, instead of HTML event attributes.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen for some reason I was under the impression that `addEventListener()` was deprecated. Perhaps I was mistaking it for something else.

Comment: [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is definitely not deprecated. In general, using HTML onevent attributes is not a good way to go. You should, generally, choose to use `addEventListener()` instead of HTML onevent attributes.

Comment: @Makyen duly noted. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can register click event listener to your pop-up's document object, and then inspect event's target to figure out from where that event is originated, then you can perform your desired action or execute a specific function.

Consider this example for better understanding.

## Addon's HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="employeeCode" id="employeeCode">
  <a href="#" id="testAnchor">adsf/a>   
  <script src="myaddon.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and in my `myaddon.js` file, I am having this code,

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if( e.target.id === 'testAnchor' ){
    var empCode = document.getElementById('employeeCode').value;
    console.log( empCode );
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI: A) The question, based on the error provided, is using a content script, not a popup. B) Questions which are unclear, etc. (e.g. debugging questions without a [mcve]) should be flagged for closure (voting to close when you have the reputation to do so). C) The issue with HTML event attributes not working in popups due to CSP is one which has multiple duplicates. It would be best to find one of those duplicates and flag for closure as a duplicate, if that's what you think the Question is about, rather than provide an answer.